# Loading properties file in Distributed application

Tags: java, spring, caching, properties

I have a set of resource properties file through which I load my spring beans. As this application being an interface layer there will be many application or services layers who might want to add their properties. So I want to design a UI and provide the provision for updating the properties file.

Let me know the best approach of handling this scenario because I cannot keep the files at server level and do any manual operations. Let me know if Spring provides any such features such that I can cache the file and load accordingly if any changes occur. Advise for better approaches

Answer (score 0):

You can read and load resource from external locations using UrlResource

[Documentation 1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/UrlResource.html) | [Documentation 2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html)

Example using annotation:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource(value = { "classpath:spring/*.xml"})
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = {
    "classpath:application.properties","http://localhost/prop/remote.properties"})
public class Server {
      .....
}
```

In this code, any values given in application.properties will get replaced by remote.properties. Please note that there will be a delay in starting server due to over the wire read. You can do same activity as some timer tasks as well.

Comment: In case if i update the application.properties file residing externally at run time will there be a delay in updating resources in remote prop file? Let me know if implementing caching mechanism on the resource might help in this scenario?

Comment: Spring by default will not reload properties with out restart. Search for Reloadable Property add-ons to achieve this.